# Interleaved Script for Shell

Tags: linux, shell

I need to write a script that will interleave the content of two different files. For example, executing './inter2files file1 file2' will give me:

file1-line1

file2*line1

file1-line2

file2*line2

The code I have so far is:

```
exec 30< file1
exec 40< file2
read line1 <& 30 
read line2 <& 40
echo $line1 
echo $line2
```

Comment: And this doesn't work because...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with a Perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

do { open($fh[$_], "<$ARGV[$_]") or die("'$ARGV[$_]' does not exist") } for (0..$#ARGV);

for ($i=0;;$i++) {
    $j=$#ARGV+1;

    $fh = $fh[$i%$j];
    if ( $_ = <$fh> ) {
            print $_;
    } else {
            $end |= 2**($i%$j);
    }

    if($end == (2**($j))-1) {
            last;
    }
}

close($_) for(@fh);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with `paste`:

```
paste -d "\n" file1 file2 > output_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare -a f1=(`cat file1`)
declare -a f2=(`cat file2`)
count=`echo ${#f1[@]}` # Number of elements in the array
#### assuming the line counts are the same between file1 and file2
i=0
while [ ${i} -le ${count} ]
do
  echo ${f1[${i}]}"   "${f2[${i}]}
  (( i=${i}+1 ))
done
```

since array declarations use memory space, if your files are huge, that might cause you unpredictable behavior, but if you are only processing few hundred lines worth files at a time, this approach should work.